# How to retrieve variable from CMS page

Tags: magento2, blocks, template, phtml, variables

If I have the following code in a CMS page to call a template:

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="gifts" template="Magento_Theme::html/gifts.phtml" product_id="68"}}'
```

How would I then retrieve the product ID in the phtml file?

I've tried:

```
$product = $this->getData('product_id');
```

But it returns empty, what is the correct way to retrieve this variable in Magento 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're using Magento 1 syntax via `$this`. In Magento 2 you should use `$block`

You can get the data by calling:

```
$product = $block->getData('product_id');
```

Or

```
$product = $block->getProductId();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, is there anything else I need to do, as both are empty.

Comment: @Aravona no that's definitely the only thing you need to do. Flush the cache and remove var/generation

Comment: Caching isn't turned on, as this is a development version of the website. Is there anything I need to do to initiate $block?

Comment: you need not to define block because Magento replace **$this** with  **$block** , So now you can use $block in template file.

Comment: Finally got it working.... now it's just the rest of the code that's broken! :)